# How is pip install using git different than just cloning a repository?

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm a beginner with Django and I'm having trouble installing django-basic-apps using pip.

If I do this...

```
$ cat requirements.txt 
git+git://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps.git

$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I end up with `lib/python2.6/site-packages/basic/blog` that does NOT have a templates directory.

If I do this...

```
git clone http://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps.git
```

I end up with a copy of `basic/blog` that DOES have a templates directory.

I suspect something about `django-basic-apps` or pip makes it not able to be installed via pip. I thought maybe reading `django-basic-apps`'s `setup.py` would lead me to the answer, but I couldn't see it.

(I should add that if I install without using pip, I'm able to get `django-basic-apps` working just fine.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you use "pip" to install something, the package's `setup.py` is used to determine what packages to install.  And this project's `setup.py`, if I'm reading it correctly, says "just install these Python packages inside the `basic` directory" — the `setup.py` makes absolutely no mention of any non-Python files it wants included in the install.

This might be deliberate on the developer's part, since it is something of a tradition for Django packages to not include templates — notoriously, even something so basic as the built-in `django.contrib.auth` comes without any templates and makes you build its little forms from the ground up each time! (Or, to cut and paste from examples elsewhere on the web.)

But if you yourself want the templates to be installed with this Python distribution, regardless of how the author has set things up, then just list the templates in the `setup.py`!  First, add something like this to the `setup.py` file:

```
template_patterns = [
    'templates/*.html',
    'templates/*/*.html',
    'templates/*/*/*.html',
    ]
```

Then, add one last variable to the `setup()` call so that it ends like this:

```
...
packages=packages,
package_data=dict( (package_name, template_patterns)
                   for package_name in packages ))
```

This asserts to the `setup()` function that every package should be accompanied by data files that are found by searching for HTML files beneath each package's `templates` directory.

Try it out, and let me know if this works on your machine too!

Comment: Thank you Brandon.   It worked, but more importantly, I understand it better now.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  I should note, for future readers, that the above code is a bit brittle and only works for templates up to two directories deep inside of "templates.html"; a full-fledged example might `os.walk()` the whole tree and find all `.html` files however deep. Too bad that `package_data` patterns do not support the zsh(1) convention: `templates/**/*.html`

Comment: Thanks Brandon, excellent answer. FWIW I highly doubt this is intentional; it would be unusual to include the templates in that location in the source repo if they weren't intended to be used with the app. Simple packaging fail is much more likely; I've filed a bug with the project to make sure the author is aware of this problem.